# stored procedure times out while subsequent runs take 1/6 the time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

So I have this stored procedure which is running very slow (and timing out) in one particular production environment. This stored procedure produces an xml of profile data. In all other environments, the sp runs very fast. After tracing the procedure in the particular environment, I found that the final "SELECT" statement was taking up 96% of the total time (should be under 30%). This statement involves multiple SELECTS, UNIONS, and JOINS. I will refer to this as the "Last Select" statement.

On subsequent runs, the "Last Select" statement, and subsequently the whole batch, took much less time. What is especially curious is that subsequent runs used many more profiles (15,000 new in the second run, 25,000 new in the third run).

Comparing the query plans, I found some interesting differences between 10000.trc and 25000.trc. Both of the following were seen in steps before the "Last Select"

1. The faster run (25K) utilizes many operations involving parallelism. I do not see any operations involving parallelism in the slow run.
2. The faster run uses “hash matches” and “merge joins” for inner and outer Joins (instead of nested loops). With a few exceptions, the slow run seems to always use nested loops.

The slow run uses many clustered index scans and clustered index seeks during the final select that the fast run does not. The slow run also uses a "concatenation" step (not found in the fast run) which appends multiple tables to make an output table.

Here is a summary of the times; [image: sp times]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS and version of that RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 Management Studio 9.00.1399.00

Answer (score 0):

In general queries that run in parallel will run faster, there are hints you can use to enforce a query to run in parallel but you want to be cautious in using them as it can for SQL server to make poor performance decisions.

Index seeks are also faster than index scans so they are what you should strive for.

Although listed above are general pointers it would really help if you could give post the last select statement.  Plus give a rough size of the tables involved.